# Output all values of a Set of strings

Tags: javascript, set

In JavaScript, what is the shortest code to output, for debugging purposes, all elements of a Set of strings? It doesn't matter if the strings are on one line or individual lines.

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add('dog');
set.add('cat');

console.log(???);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected.

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add('dog');
set.add('cat');
console.log(...set);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [create an Array out of the Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), then log that:

```js
const set = new Set();
set.add('dog');
set.add('cat');

console.log(Array.from(set));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ES6 method

```
.forEach()
```

So in full:

```
const set = new Set();
set.add('dog');
set.add('cat');

set.forEach(item => console.log(item))
```